# Calling iot:attachPolicy from AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I'm trying to attach a policy from a AWS Lambda and I'm getting 403 with the following error:

'User: arn:aws:sts::acc-nbr:assumed-role/XXX/XXX is not authorized to perform: iot:AttachPolicy on resource: XXXX'.

I've added 'IotFullAccess' to the role selected in the lambda but the issue is still there. Any  suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was because codestar was adding a boundary to the role, so even if I added the permission for iot:AttachPolicy, this was not inside the boundary and AWS didn't take this policy into consideration.